# буфер ostream защищен мьютексом?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

имеется такой надуманный участок кода, поток вывода намеренно не защищен мьютексом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <thread>

void print(std::string_view message)
{
  for (int i = 0;i < 10000;++i) {
    std::cout << message;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(print, "hello\n");
  std::thread t2(print, "aloha\n");
  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

вывод получается какого-то такого вида рандомный

```
...
hello
hello
aloha
hello
aloha
...
```

но почему слова выводятся целиком, не перемешиваясь символами например так `haelohallo`, это значит что буфер потока вывода защищен мьютексом и не позволяет в него записывать нескольким потокам или устроено каким-то другим хитрым образом?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream

Comment: @dIm0n но в обычном ostream по цепочке наследования просто  `basic_ostream` а не `basic_osyncstream`, но синхронизация как будто есть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандарт ([[iostreams.threadsafety]](https://eel.is/c++draft/iostreams.threadsafety)) говорит нам:

> Concurrent access to a stream object, stream buffer object, or C Library stream by multiple threads may result in a data race unless otherwise specified.
> [Note: Data races result in undefined behavior.
> — end note]

Но для стандартных потоков явно оговаривает ([[iostream.objects.overview]](https://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.objects.overview#5)):

> Concurrent access to a synchronized standard iostream object's formatted and unformatted input and output functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads does not result in a data race.
> [Note: Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by multiple threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters.
> — end note]

Вольный перевод:

> Параллельный доступ к объекту потока, буферу потока или потокам из библиотеки Си множеством нитей может вызвать гонку данных, если иное не указано.
> [Замечание: Гонка данных вызывает неопределённое поведение.]

> Параллельный доступ к функциям объекта стандартного потока ввода/вывода (как форматированного, так и не форматированного) или стандартного потока Си множеством нитей **не** приводит к гонке данных.
> [Замечание: Пользователям всё ещё необходимо синхронизировать одновременное использование этих объектов, если они хотят избежать чередование символов.]

Таким образом, синхронизация обеспечивается только для `cin`/`cout`/`cerr`. Для них гарантируется, что символы при вводе/выводе не будут пропадать/дублироваться, но, строго говоря, это не гарантирует, что даже при выводе целых строк они не будут перемежаться, хотя по факту это и оказывается так на большинстве реализаций. Также стоит учесть, что конструкции вида:

```
std::cout << "Message: " << message;
```

будут иметь неожидаемый эффект почти во всех реализациях.

Для всех прочих потоков (файловых/строковых итп) всё это являтся неопределённым поведением и, как обычно, может вызвать всё что угодно: от корректной работы до исчезновения/дублирования данных в выводе/ порчи объекта потока, спонтанных самовозгораний и вылета демонов из носа.

> буфер ostream защищен мьютексом?

Строго говоря, использование именно мьютекса не обязательно, но на большинстве реализаций для стандартных потоков — да, так и есть. Т.к. обычно плюсовые стандартные потоки — это обёртки для Сишных (фактически стандарт подразумевает такую реализацию), то конкретика зависит от реализации libc. Так мьютексы или аналогичные им структуры используются в glibc, uclibc, newlib и BSD libc (само собой, если сама libc была собрана с поддержкой многопоточности.).

Для файловых и строковых потоков ни какая синхронизация не обязательна. Так в гнутой libstdс++ её нет, хотя во всех перечисленных libc Сишные файловые потоки по умолчанию синхронизируются аналогично стандартным.

---

Как уже отметили в комментариях, в С++20 для того, чтобы адекватно писать в поток параллельно добавят [`osyncstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream).

---

<sub>Спасибо *@dIm0n* за указание на ошибки в изначальном ответе.</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374525/13970074

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.objects.overview#5

Comment: то есть если я записываю очень огромную строку в буфер, то все это время другой поток который тоже хочет записать крутиться в бесконечном цикле ожидая разблокировки spin-lock?

Comment: @Ildar, тут я тоже ошибся — сделал вывод на основе эксперимента, но там просто не попалась блокировка... посмотрел сейчас — и в glibc, и в uclibc действительно мьютексы...