# Как грамотно завершить неизвестное заранее количество потоков C++?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здраствуйте, у меня появился вопрос: как грамотно завершить неизвестное заранее количество потоков? Тоесть программа должна запустить одну функцию в несколько потоков, вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int func() {   //функция которою выполняют потоки
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    std::cout << "hello" << endl;
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   int numb;
    cin>>numb; //пользователь вносит количество потоков
   for ( int j = 0; j <= numb; j++ ) {
      new std::thread(func);
   }
   //здесь main должна ждать
   cout<<"bonjour"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что функция main не дожидается завершения потоков и влезает посередние. Вот что я имею ввиду:

```
root@PCKali:/home/kali/eclipse-workspace/test/Debug# ./test
5
hello
hello
hellohello
hello
hello

hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello**bonjour**
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

bonjour появляется между hello (Выделил звёздочками), а мне нужно чтобы main дожидалась окончании потоков. Я знаю про функцию .join(); но я не знаю что писать перед точкой, так как названия потокам не даётся, потому что пользователь выбирает их количество. Может я делаю не правильно ещё на этапе создания потоков? Подскажите, пожалуйста. (Надеюсь всё нормально объяснил, если вдруг что - спрашивайте в комментах)

Comment: Заведите вектор `std::vector<std::thread> threads;` и сохраняйте ссылки на потоки там. В конце делайте join по ним -- `for (auto& th : threads) th.join();`. [Вот пример](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/)

Comment: В [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166712/398802) уже показали ведь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) создаем `num` потоков с функцией `foo` в контейнере `vector`

(2) присоединяем потоки к главному потоку обычным проходом по `vector` с применением метода `join`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void foo() {} // функция которую выполняют потоки

int main() 
{
  int num;
  std::cin >> num; // пользователь вносит количество потоков

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  threads.reserve(num);     
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {         // (1)
    threads.emplace_back(foo);         
  }

  for (auto& thread : threads) {          // (2)
    thread.join();                        
  }

  std::cout << "only master thread is working here\n";

  return 0;
}
```

---

что касается вашего участка кода:

1. создавая объект потока с помощью `new` вы ни где не сохраняете указатель на выделенную память, если уж вам нужны указатели на потоки, то закидывайте указатели в `vector` например, потом `join` или `detach` их, и уж потом позаботьтесь об освобождении памяти выделенной под каждый `thread`
2. синхронизация потока вывода в теле вашей функции `func` тема отдельного вопроса и об этом стоит позаботиться

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint32_t numb = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> numb;
    std::mutex threadMtx;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(numb);

    for (uint32_t id = 0; id < numb; ++id) {
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([&threadMtx](){
            for (uint8_t cn = 1; cn <= 5; ++cn) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(threadMtx);
                std::cout << "From Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id()
                          << " >> Hello [ " << std::to_string(cn) << " ] " << std::endl << std::flush;
            }
        }));
    }

    for (auto &thread : threads) {
        if (thread.joinable()) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Bonjour" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
// Сonsole output:

Please enter a number: 3

From Thread 139909013223168 >> Hello [ 1 ] 
From Thread 139909013223168 >> Hello [ 2 ] 
From Thread 139909013223168 >> Hello [ 3 ] 
From Thread 139909013223168 >> Hello [ 4 ] 
From Thread 139909013223168 >> Hello [ 5 ] 
From Thread 139908996437760 >> Hello [ 1 ] 
From Thread 139908996437760 >> Hello [ 2 ] 
From Thread 139908996437760 >> Hello [ 3 ] 
From Thread 139908996437760 >> Hello [ 4 ] 
From Thread 139908996437760 >> Hello [ 5 ] 
From Thread 139909004830464 >> Hello [ 1 ] 
From Thread 139909004830464 >> Hello [ 2 ] 
From Thread 139909004830464 >> Hello [ 3 ] 
From Thread 139909004830464 >> Hello [ 4 ] 
From Thread 139909004830464 >> Hello [ 5 ] 
Bonjour
```

Comment: А зачем тут мьютекс? Да и лямбда читаемости не добавляет...

Comment: Мьютекс используется для синхронизации вывода сообщений, ибо при не использовании метода синхронизации, сообщения выводятся в хаотичном порядке. А на счет лямбды, я ее использую при создание временных функциях.

Comment: Разве std::cout не имеет внутреннего мьютекса (аналогично printf())?

Comment: @avp Имеет некоторое подобие, которое обеспечивает отсутствие гонки (неопределенного поведения), но все же, рекомендуется со стороны пользователя обеспечивать синхронизацию, если есть такая возможность. 
[Тут](https://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.objects.overview#5) говориться как раз о том, что пользователь все таки должен использовать синхронизацию, если он хочет избежать чередования символов.

Comment: @avp только же был вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166065/398802

Comment: @dIm0n, там слишком много букв, а ответ (ДА/НЕТ) как-то не выделен (я сходу его не увидел)